# Coldfusion condition in jquery call

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I want to call a jquery function only when the browser is mobile which I am checking in Coldfusion, can I do the below call. I am not getting the desired results when I am on the mobile browser. Is the below call even a correct way to do it? Any inputs are appreciated. Thanks!

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function(e) {
        testfunction(); 
    });

    <cfif mobile>
    function testfunction() {
        /* function code here for mobile */
    }
   </cfif>

   <cfif not mobile>
    function testfunction() {
        /* different code for desktop function code here */
    }
   </cfif>
   </script>
```

Comment: That should work fine. You probably need to name your functions differently though.

Comment: Take things one step at a time.  First, using ColdFusion only, make sure you are assigning the correct value to the mobile variable.  Once you know that's working, the lack of desired results is a javascript problem.

Comment: Yes, the coldfusion Var is set correctly, checked it both on desktop and mobile, having issues in the JS. thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it is working fine. We are able to add a ColdFusion condition inside the script. If the browser is a mobile browser, the first `testfunction()` is called. Otherwise, the second `testfunction()` is invoked. So it's definitely working. Perhaps you are not detecting the mobile browser correctly via code? Maybe this is the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little simpler:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function(e) {
        testfunction(); 
    });

    <cfif mobile>
    function testfunction() {
        /* function code here for mobile */
    }
   <cfelse>
    function testfunction() {
        /* different code for desktop function code here */
    }
   </cfif>
</script>
```

But I feel a little strange with having two functions of the same name on the screen. If it were me, I'd probably go with this:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function(e) {
        testfunction(); 
    });

    function testfunction() {
        <cfif mobile>
            /* function code here for mobile */
        <cfelse>
            /* different code for desktop function code here */
        </cfif>
    }
</script>
```